# Crear un diccionario y la frecuencia de las palabras

Tags: python, diccionarios, frecuencia

No he podido resolverlo, la pregunta, es escribir una función en Python que reciba como entrada una lista de palabras y devuelva un diccionario donde las claves sean las palabras de la lista y los valores sean el número de veces que aparece cada palabra en la lista. Luego, escribe el diccionario resultante en un archivo de texto llamado "frecuencias.txt" utilizando el siguiente formato: :  :

Comment: Esta pregunta se ha hecho [muchas veces](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+contar+ocurrencias) en el sitio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo podrías escribir la función en Python para lograr eso:

```
def contar_frecuencias(lista_palabras):
    frecuencias = {}
    
    for palabra in lista_palabras:
        if palabra in frecuencias:
            frecuencias[palabra] += 1
        else:
            frecuencias[palabra] = 1
    
    return frecuencias

# Ejemplo de uso
lista = ["hola", "mundo", "hola", "Python", "mundo", "mundo"]
frecuencias = contar_frecuencias(lista)

# Escribir el diccionario en un archivo de texto
with open("frecuencias.txt", "w") as archivo:
    for palabra, frecuencia in frecuencias.items():
        archivo.write(f"{palabra}: {frecuencia}\n")
```

En este ejemplo, la función **contar_frecuencias** toma una lista de palabras como entrada y crea un diccionario llamado **frecuencias**. Luego, recorre la lista de palabras y va actualizando las frecuencias en el diccionario. Finalmente, el diccionario resultante se escribe en el archivo "frecuencias.txt".

Asegúrate de tener el archivo "frecuencias.txt" en la misma ubicación que tu script de Python antes de ejecutarlo. ¡Espero que esto te ayude a resolver tu problema!

Comment: Puedes ahorrarte el `if/else` colocando `frecuencias[palabra] = frecuencias.get(palabra, 0) + 1`